# Printing the current spawned users during a load test in Locust

Tags: python, events, load-testing, locust

Is there a way to print the current spawned users during a load test every 1 second? So far I have only been able to print that all users have been spawned with the `spawning_complete` event. I figured since the web UI can get the current users and put it in a graph I should be able to print it in the console.

I have searched and searched but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You'd need to spawn your own greenlet to have something run in parallel to your code. The docs explain how to do that [here](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html?#run-a-background-greenlet), with an example of monitoring the fail ratio on the master instance and stopping the test above a certain threshold. You could adapt that to just print out the number of currently running users instead, using the [`user_count` property of the runner](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?#locust.runners.Runner.user_count):

```
import gevent
from locust import events
from locust.runners import STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP, MasterRunner, LocalRunner

def print_current_users(environment):
    while not environment.runner.state in [STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP]:
        time.sleep(2)
        print(f"Currently running users: {environment.runner.user_count}")


@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    # dont run this on workers, we only care about the aggregated numbers
    if isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner) or isinstance(environment.runner, LocalRunner):
        gevent.spawn(print_current_users, environment)
```

Comment: Nice. But it will fail on repeated (gui) runs. I think you should spawn the greenlet on test_start event instead of init

Comment: This worked! It seems to be difficult to find answers like these when using Locust

Comment: @Cyberwiz true. Would probably need something to stop the greenlet on test_stop, too.

Comment: Yea that would be nice. But I guess most people will not start new tests within 2s, so I think that is a minor issue :)